# json data changed in the params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parameters

This is a webhook activity I am trying do using postman. The post content  is the below json.

```
 {
   "model":{
      "id":"560a32d2a1dcb7902a7ad596",
      "name":"cool features",
      "pos":32767.5
   },
   "action":{
      "id":"567537b94332a7d8489a0d26",
      "idMemberCreator":"55024f3fdd60428e915d2c2b",
      "data":{
         "board":{
            "shortLink":"SUDki3AR",
            "name":"recipe",
            "id":"560a31fad96886a87cabf39a"
         },
         "list":{
            "name":"cool features",
            "id":"560a32d2a1dcb7902a7ad596"
         },
         "card":{
            "shortLink":"sufSA867",
            "idShort":18,
            "name":"added",
            "id":"567537b94332a7d8489a0d25"
         }
      },
      "type":"createCard",
      "date":"2015-12-19T10:55:53.904Z",

   }
}
```

rails strips away the action key value from params. I can only get it using `request.raw_post` . But it is a string . Is there a way to get the action value in the json in params? String manipulation would be very difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails sets the params `controller` and `action` on every request, so it overwrites your `action`.

As you already found out, you can get the request string and as you know it's json, you can parse it (by the way: your json is invalid, an extra `,` after `date`):

```
action = JSON.parse(request.raw_post)['action']
```